# Get the first 100 elements of OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x

`preresult` is an `OrderedDict()`.

I want to save the first 100 elements in it. Or keep `preresult` but delete everything other than the first 100 elements.

The structure is like this

```
stats = {'a':   {'email1':4, 'email2':3}, 
         'the': {'email1':2, 'email3':4},
         'or':  {'email1':2, 'email3':1}}
```

Will islice work for it？ Mine tells `itertool.islice` does not have `items`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `itertools`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> preresult = collections.OrderedDict(zip(range(200), range(200)))
>>> list(islice(preresult, 100))[-10:]
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

This returns only keys. If you want items, use `iteritems` (or just `items` in Python 3):

```
>>> list(islice(preresult.iteritems(), 100))[-10:]
[(90, 90), (91, 91), (92, 92), (93, 93), (94, 94), (95, 95), (96, 96), (97, 97), (98, 98), (99, 99)]
```

Comment: @KurzedMetal, you need to convert it to a list before regular slicing will work. `islice` is more efficient because it can skip the unneeded items.

Comment: sorry, my mistake :P i really need to reread itertools and collections documentation.

Comment: @senderle It says OrderDict does not have iteritems. I use python 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can slice the keys of OrderedDict and copy it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = OrderedDict()
for i in xrange(10):
    a[i] = i*i

b = OrderedDict()
for i in a.keys()[0:5]:
    b[i] = a[i]
```

b is a sliced version of a

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in list(od.items())[:100]:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't we just convert the list into a dictionary with keys and values, then slide it as you need, then put it back into an orderedDict?

Here's how I did it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#defined an OrderedDict()

stats = OrderedDict()

#loading the ordered list with 100 keys
for i in range(100):
    stats[str(i)] = {'email'+str(i):i,'email'+str(i+1):i+1}

#Then slicing the first 20 elements from the OrderedDict
#I first convert it to a list, then slide, then put it back as an OrderedDict

st = OrderedDict(list(stats.items())[:20])

print  (stats)

print (st)
```

The output of this will be as follows. I reduced the first one to 10 items and sliced it to only the first 5 items:

```
OrderedDict([('0', {'email0': 0, 'email1': 1}), ('1', {'email1': 1, 'email2': 2}), ('2', {'email2': 2, 'email3': 3}), ('3', {'email3': 3, 'email4': 4}), ('4', {'email4': 4, 'email5': 5}), ('5', {'email5': 5, 'email6': 6}), ('6', {'email6': 6, 'email7': 7}), ('7', {'email7': 7, 'email8': 8}), ('8', {'email8': 8, 'email9': 9}), ('9', {'email9': 9, 'email10': 10})])

OrderedDict([('0', {'email0': 0, 'email1': 1}), ('1', {'email1': 1, 'email2': 2}), ('2', {'email2': 2, 'email3': 3}), ('3', {'email3': 3, 'email4': 4}), ('4', {'email4': 4, 'email5': 5})])
```

I did a print (dict(st)) to get this:

```
{'0': {'email0': 0, 'email1': 1}, '1': {'email1': 1, 'email2': 2}, '2': {'email2': 2, 'email3': 3}, '3': {'email3': 3, 'email4': 4}, '4': {'email4': 4, 'email5': 5}}
```